# perl using xml passed from stdin using XML::Simple

Tags: xml, perl

i want to read an xml from stdin.

For parsing the xml I would use `$data = $xml->XMLin(<STDIN>)`, anyway which is the most efficient way for evaluating all the data passed from stdin without rewriting it into a file?

If I use `$data = $xml->XMLin(<STDIN>)` it does not work.

Any suggestion?

Main goal is to use the data passed from the stdin in the most efficient way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 $data = $xml->XMLin('-');
```

> Note, the filename '-' can be used to parse from STDIN.

Comment: what's the meaning of "-" is?

Comment: It's just a special symbol which XML::Simple understand as STDIN. This is XML::Simple feature described in docs.

Comment: It's quite common for Unix utilities and Perl functions that expect a filename to recognise '-' as meaning read from STDIN.

Answer (score 4):

Passing a reference to the builtin filehandle also works using typeglob notation.

```
my $data = XMLin(\*STDIN);
```